# Is onClick property and function exposed on react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to delay the onClick event on the option element of react-select.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { components } from "react-select";

const Option = props => {
  const { label, data, onClick } = props;

  return (
    <components.Option
      {...props}
      onClick={() => {
        setTimeout(onClick, 100);
      }}>
      <div>Some custom stuff here</div>
    </components.Option>
  );
};

export default Option;
```

Expected behavior:

1. user clicks on the option (in the dropdown list)
2. react-select should not do anything for 100ms
3. after 100ms react-select does his job

I already tried this with the props `selectOption`, `onChange`, and `onClick`
on the `Select` and `components.Options` components but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Found it :)
Not sure if its proper way to do it but it works.

```
  const { innerProps } = props;
  const { onClick } = innerProps;
  props.innerProps.onClick = e => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      onClick(e);
    }, 100);
  };
```

Comment: You don't happen to have the full example?